# Failed to configure ForgeRock openAM deployment

Tags: tomcat, openam, forgerock

I am trying to setup an openAM deployment in minikube. I have followed the instructions in this page https://medium.com/forgerock/forgerock-am-6-5-deployment-on-k8s-78da7330dd98. Since this is pretty old i modified the docker file so as to be able to use the latest openAm version provided.

```
FROM openjdk:11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl
# Set environment variables
 ENV TOMCAT_VERSION=9.0.74 \
     CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
#     # Install Tomcat
RUN         mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat && \
             curl -Ls https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v${TOMCAT_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local/tomcat --strip-components=1 && \
                 rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xmx2g -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Xmx1024m \
  -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true"
EXPOSE 8080
ENV AM_VERSION 7.3.0
ADD ./artifacts/AM-${AM_VERSION}.zip /tmp

RUN unzip /tmp/AM-${AM_VERSION}.zip -d /opt
RUN cp /opt/openam/AM-${AM_VERSION}.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/openam.war
RUN rm /tmp/AM-${AM_VERSION}.zip
ENV AM_HOME /opt/openam
ENV PATH $AM_HOME:$PATH
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

This works fine and i got into the configurator page just like the video in the page. The difference is that i always get an error at the end.

[image: configurator]

The logs inside the pod indicate that there is am invalid administrator port configured (-1) even if i have configured a port number.

```
root@am-594bc677f8-wz9kr:/usr/local/tomcat# cat /root/openam/var/install.log
05/04/2023 05:31:18:023 PM UTC: Checking license acceptance...
05/04/2023 05:31:18:024 PM UTC: License terms accepted.
License, legal-notices/Forgerock_License.txt, has been accepted.
License Hash: Yalwb9SLaQCqu0NjseRm+vqup41ucHzs83eS3VP3uZI=.
05/04/2023 05:31:18:030 PM UTC: Checking configuration directory /root/openam.
05/04/2023 05:31:18:476 PM UTC: ...Success.
05/04/2023 05:31:19:599 PM UTC: Extracting DS, please wait...
05/04/2023 05:31:26:077 PM UTC: Complete
05/04/2023 05:31:26:077 PM UTC: Running DS setup
05/04/2023 05:31:26:078 PM UTC: ...Failed An error occurred while initializing configuration of embedded server with server root '/root/openam/opends': Administration connector port '-1' is not in allowed range 1, 65535
AMSetupServlet.processRequest: error com.sun.identity.setup.ConfiguratorException: configurator.embsetupopendsfailed
    at com.sun.identity.setup.EmbeddedOpenDS.setupOpenDS(EmbeddedOpenDS.java:450)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.EmbeddedOpenDS.setup(EmbeddedOpenDS.java:292)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.setupEmbeddedDS(AMSetupServlet.java:804)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.setupSMDatastore(AMSetupServlet.java:827)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.configure(AMSetupServlet.java:890)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.processRequest(AMSetupServlet.java:551)
    at com.sun.identity.config.DefaultSummary.createDefaultConfig(DefaultSummary.java:125)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.click.util.ClickUtils.invokeMethod(ClickUtils.java:3317)
    at org.apache.click.util.ClickUtils.invokeListener(ClickUtils.java:2088)
    at org.apache.click.control.AbstractControl$1.onAction(AbstractControl.java:228)
    at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(ActionEventDispatcher.java:259)
    at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvents(ActionEventDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.apache.click.ActionEventDispatcher.fireActionEvents(ActionEventDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.performOnProcess(ClickServlet.java:746)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.processAjaxPageEvents(ClickServlet.java:1860)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.processPage(ClickServlet.java:559)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.handleRequest(ClickServlet.java:383)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.doGet(ClickServlet.java:276)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.headers.SecureCookieFilter.doFilter(SecureCookieFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.headers.DisableSameSiteCookiesFilter.doFilter(DisableSameSiteCookiesFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.headers.SetHeadersFilter.doFilter(SetHeadersFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.headers.SetHeadersFilter.doFilter(SetHeadersFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.validation.RequestEntitySizeVerificationFilter.doFilter(RequestEntitySizeVerificationFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditContextFilter.doFilter(AuditContextFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.forgerock.opendj.server.embedded.EmbeddedDirectoryServerException: An error occurred while initializing configuration of embedded server with server root '/root/openam/opends': Administration connector port '-1' is not in allowed range 1, 65535
    at org.forgerock.opendj.server.embedded.EmbeddedDirectoryServer.initializeConfiguration(EmbeddedDirectoryServer.java:489)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.EmbeddedOpenDS.setupOpenDS(EmbeddedOpenDS.java:416)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: com.forgerock.opendj.cli.ArgumentException: Administration connector port '-1' is not in allowed range 1, 65535
    at org.forgerock.opendj.setup.model.SetupUtils.validatePortIsInRange(SetupUtils.java:359)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.setup.model.Setup.validatePort(Setup.java:1102)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.setup.model.Setup.validateFreePort(Setup.java:1080)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.setup.model.Setup.adminPort(Setup.java:372)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.server.embedded.EmbeddedDirectoryServer.initializeConfiguration(EmbeddedDirectoryServer.java:467)
    ... 70 more


Dumping all configuration parameters...

Request Parameters:
acceptLicense = true
actionLink = createDefaultConfig
ADMIN_CONFIRM_PWD = #########
ADMIN_PWD = #########
AM_ENC_KEY = #########
BASE_DIR = /root/openam
COOKIE_DOMAIN = 192.168.49.2
DATA_STORE = embedded
DIRECTORY_ADMIN_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_JMX_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_SERVER = 192.168.49.2
DIRECTORY_SSL = SSL
DS_DIRMGRPASSWD = #########
locale = en
PLATFORM_LOCALE = en_US
SERVER_HOST = 192.168.49.2
SERVER_PORT = 30085
SERVER_URI = /openam/config/defaultSummary.htm
SERVER_URL = http://192.168.49.2:30085/openam/config/defaultSummary.htm
SESSION_ROOT_SUFFIX = ou=openam-session
SESSION_STORE_TYPE = none

Main configuration items:
acceptLicense = true
actionLink = createDefaultConfig
ADMIN_PWD = #########
AM_COEXIST = false
AM_ENC_KEY = #########
AM_REALM = true
AMLDAPUSERPASSWD = #########
AMSDK_I18N_KEY = a101
AUTH_DEFAULT_CONFIG = ldapService
BASE_DIR = /root/openam
CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.configuration.impl.ConfigurationInstanceImpl
CONSOLE_URI = /openam
COOKIE_DOMAIN = 
COOKIE_ENCODE = false
DATA_STORE = embedded
DATASTORE_NOTIFICATION = true
DATASTORE_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.datastore.impl.IdRepoDataStoreProvider
DB_NAME = appData
DEBUG_DIR = debug
DEBUG_SUBDIR = debug
DEFAULT_AUTH_MODULE = DataStore
DEFAULT_ORG = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
DIRECTORY_ADMIN_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_JMX_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_PORT = -1
DIRECTORY_SERVER = 192.168.49.2
DIRECTORY_SSL = SSL
DISABLE_PERSISTENT_SEARCH = aci,um
DIT_LOADED = false
DS_DIRMGRDN = cn=Directory Manager
DS_DIRMGRPASSWD = #########
DS_UM_SCHEMA = sms
ENCADADMINPASSWD = #########
ENCADMINPASSWD = #########
ENCDSDIRMGRPASSWD = #########
GlobalAccessTokenModificationScriptId = d22f9a0c-426a-4466-b95e-d0f125b0d5fa
GlobalAmazonProfileNormalizationScriptId = 6b3cfd48-62d3-48ff-a96f-fe8f3a22ab30
GlobalAppleProfileNormalizationScriptId = 484e6246-dbc6-4288-97e6-54e55431402e
GlobalAuthenticationTreeDecisionNodeScriptId = 01e1a3c0-038b-4c16-956a-6c9d89328cff
GlobalClientSideAuthModuleScriptId = c827d2b4-3608-4693-868e-bbcf86bd87c7
GlobalClientSideDeviceIdMatchScriptId = 157298c0-7d31-4059-a95b-eeb08473b7e5
GlobalConfigProviderScriptId = 5e854779-6ec1-4c39-aeba-0477e0986646
GlobalDeviceProfileMatchDecisionNodeScriptId = 13e3f263-9cd3-4844-8d1c-040fd0dd02eb
GlobalEntitlementConditionScriptId = 9de3eb62-f131-4fac-a294-7bd170fd4acb
GlobalFacebookProfileNormalizationScriptId = bae1d54a-e97d-4997-aa5d-c027f21af82c
GlobalGitHubProfileNormalizationScriptId = a7a78773-445b-4eca-bb93-409e86bced81
GlobalGoogleProfileNormalizationScriptId = 58d29080-4563-480b-89bb-1e7719776a21
GlobalInstagramProfileNormalizationScriptId = 1244e639-4a31-401d-ab61-d75133d8dc9e
GlobalItsmeProfileNormalizationScriptId = 3d97c436-42c0-4dd0-a571-ea6f34f752b3
GlobalLinkedInProfileNormalizationScriptId = 8862ca8f-7770-4af5-a888-ac0df0947f36
GlobalMayActScriptId = c735de08-f8f2-4e69-aa4a-2d8d3d438323
GlobalMicrosoftProfileNormalizationScriptId = 73cecbfc-dad0-4395-be6a-6858ee3a80e5
GlobalNormalizedProfileToIdentityScriptId = ed685f9f-5909-4726-86e8-22bd38b47663
GlobalNormalizedProfileToManagedUserScriptId = 58c824ae-84ed-4724-82cd-db128fc3f6c
GlobalOauth2AuthorizeEndpointDataProviderScriptId = 3f93ef6e-e54a-4393-aba1-f322656db28a
GlobalOAuth2EvaluateScopeScriptId = da56fe60-8b38-4c46-a405-d6b306d4b336
GlobalOAuth2ValidateScopeScriptId = 25e6c06d-cf70-473b-bd28-26931edc476b
GlobalOidcClaimsScriptId = 36863ffb-40ec-48b9-94b1-9a99f71cc3b5
GlobalSalesforceProfileNormalizationScriptId = 312e951f-70c5-49d2-a9ae-93aef909d5df
GlobalSaml2IdpAttributeMapperScriptId = c4f22465-2368-4e27-8013-e6399974fd48
GlobalServerSideAuthModuleScriptId = 7e3d7067-d50f-4674-8c76-a3e13a810c33
GlobalServerSideDeviceIdMatchScriptId = 703dab1a-1921-4981-98dd-b8e5349d8548
GlobalSocialIdPProfileTransformationScriptId = 1d475815-72cb-42eb-aafd-4026989d28a7
GlobalTwitterProfileNormalizationScriptId = 8e298710-b55e-4085-a464-88a375a4004b
GlobalVKontakteProfileNormalizationScriptId = 403cf226-6051-4368-8b72-9ba14f9a5140
GlobalWeChatProfileNormalizationScriptId = 472534ec-a25f-468d-a606-3fb1935190df
GlobalWordPressProfileNormalizationScriptId = 91d197de-5916-4dca-83b5-9a4df26e7159
GlobalYahooProfileNormalizationScriptId = 424da748-82cc-4b54-be6f-82bd64d82a74
HASHADMINPASSWD = #########
ie7fix = 21
IS_INSTALL_VARDIR = baseDir
IS_PRODNAME = /openam
KEYSTORE-KEY-PASSWORD = #########
LDAP_CONNECTION_MODE = LDAP
locale = en
LOG_DIR = audit
LOG_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.log.impl.LogProvider
MONAGENT_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.monitoring.impl.AgentProvider
MONSAML2_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.monitoring.impl.FedMonSAML2SvcProvider
NORMALIZED_ORGBASE = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
NORMALIZED_RS = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
NoScriptDefined = [Empty]
OLDCON_DEPLOY_URI = /openam
ORG_BASE = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
ORG_NAMING_ATTR = o
ORG_OBJECT_CLASS = sunismanagedorganization
ORG_ROOT_SUFFIX = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
OUTPUT_DIR = basedir/uri
PAM_SERVICE_NAME = other
People_NM_ORG_ROOT_SUFFIX = People_dc=openam_dc=forgerock_dc=org
PLATFORM_LOCALE = en_US
ROOT_SUFFIX = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
ROOTURL_PROVIDER_CLASS = org.forgerock.openam.federation.plugin.rooturl.impl.FmRootUrlProvider
RS_RDN = openam
SERVER_HOST = 192.168.49.2
SERVER_PORT = 30085
SERVER_PROTO = http
SERVER_URI = /openam
SERVER_URL = http://192.168.49.2:30085
SESSION_PROVIDER_CLASS = com.sun.identity.plugin.session.impl.FMSessionProvider
SESSION_ROOT_SUFFIX = ou=openam-session
SESSION_STORE_TYPE = none
SM_CONFIG_BASEDN = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
SM_CONFIG_BASEDN_RDNA = dc
SM_CONFIG_BASEDN_RDNV = openam
SM_CONFIG_ROOT_SUFFIX = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
SM_ROOT_SUFFIX_HAT = dc=openam^dc=forgerock^dc=org
SMS_OBJECT_CLASS = SmsWrapperObject
UM_DIRECTORY_PORT = -1
UM_DIRECTORY_SERVER = 192.168.49.2
UM_DS_DIRMGRDN = cn=Directory Manager
UM_DS_DIRMGRPASSWD = #########
UM_ENABLED = true
UM_NORMALIZED_ORGBASE = dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
UM_SSL = true
USER_HOME = /root
USER_NAMING_ATTR = uid
USER_OBJECT_CLASS = inetorgperson
USER_PROFILE_CHOICE = false
VERSION = ForgeRock Access Management 7.2.1 (2023-March-31 20:54)
XML_ENCODING = ISO-8859-1

Finished dumping all configuration parameters
```

Is there a way to provide this configuration upon deployment and avoid this buggy configuration wizard ?

Comment: created issue in forgerock community https://community.forgerock.com/t/failed-to-configure-forgerock-openam-deployment/3741

Answer (score 0):

ForgeRock themselves have been setting up a repo to provide deployments on k8s.
It’s called ForgeOps and is available on GitHub: https://github.com/ForgeRock/forgeops

The default model is to deploy AM and IDM as a platform, but there are also default profiles to just setup AM.

They also provide uptodate Dockerfiles for everything in their product bundles you can use. You will find descriptions for that in the ForgeOps Docs.

Comment: I am aware of this repo, i have already installed CDK successfully on minikube. But i have the task of installing am for an integration demo in a very restricted lab which has no web access , python3 , kustomize , limited resources etc and i though that was the easiest way

Comment: You can probably use kustomize to just generate the Kubernetes resource files and use those dockerimages. You don’t need all the tools to do the deployment, but you can use it as a blueprint and use the init container etc